# Populating Outlook 2010 Suggested Contacts (Auto Complete)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

There's a feature in Outlook that autocompletes contacts based on the people you have emailed previously. My Exchange server crashed and I ended up recovering from a ost which worked well but I no longer have this functionality.

Is there a way to repopulate the suggested contacts list?

Answer (score 0):

There is a program that I have used in the past to do this. I often format my machines around the house (once every other year). I end up forgetting to backup the `nk2` file which contains the autocomplete information for Outlook.

One thing though, you will need to have a spreadsheet or database of the people that you wish to add to the autocomplete. You may be able to find a scrapper for Outlook that can compile this information from your emails, but I'm not sure of one.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html

Comment: I have used that application and can confirm it works well. If you still have the contacts in your contacts list, you can use this program to import them direct from there to your auto complete contacts, but you must close outlook first to do it.